# Emulate multiple Bluetooth Devices

Tags: linux, unix, bluetooth, emulation, bluez

I want to use a linux machine and a bluetooth dongle to simulate multiple bluetooth devices (let's say 15).
Is there a way of doing that with a single dongle? 
The simulated Bluetooth "devices" do not need any functionality at first, just to be discoverable and connectable.

Purpose: I want to connect as many bluetooth devices as possible to a system, to check what happens after a certain amount of devices. But I dont want to buy that many phones/bt players/etc. :D

Does anyone have some experiences in that? Thanks^^

Comment: I have a similar use case, did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am pretty sure that I will end up with 15 dongles. 
Do you know any tool that let's you specify BT profiles w/ versions?